# Remove files from a folder using list of a filename?

Tags: file, powershell, arraylist, cmd, delete-file

I am trying to delete file from a folder which has 3,500 + files.

FolderA(3,500+Files), FolderB(<260 Files).

What I want is that I want a  **FolderA(3,500+Files) - FolderA(list.txt) = Missing files**.

I have tried :

Get-Content c:\path\to\list.txt | Remove-Item

It doesn't work.

FolderA has over 3,500 files and within the folder i have a file called "**list.txt**" which has list of all files which I would like to delete from **FolderA**

Hope this make sense.

Thanks,
Yogs

Comment: Can you include a sample of the `list.txt` contents?

Comment: Here is the sample list:AAN919
AAU569
ABA457
ABA548
ABB717
ABE555
AHH342
AHH347
AHH348
AHH457
AHN024
AHN032
AHN272
BLD093
BMQ858
BNF800
BNF806
BNG045
BNG047
BNG052
BNG059
BNG069
BNG072
BNG113
BNG120
BNG123
BNG125
BNG126
BNG144
BNG155
BNG159
BNG161
BNG163
BNG165
BNG167
BNG169
BNG207

Comment: If the files are named exactly as they appear in the list, the only missing thing is a previous `cd c:\somewhere\folderA` so the `Remove-Item` process the correct element.

Comment: Here is what I have tried exactly: 1. **GET-Content C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\missing2\ToBeDeleted.txt | Remove-Item**


2. **Get-ChildItem -exclude (gc ToBeDeleted.txt) | Remove-Item -whatif**

3. **If (C:\Users\gggggg\Desktop\missing2 $ToBeDeleted.txt){ Remove-Item $ToBeDeleted.txt }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd "C:\Users\gggggg\Desktop\missing2" 
Get-Content "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\missing2\ToBeDeleted.txt" | Remove-Item
```

Change active folder to the folder to be processed, get the list and remove each item

For a batch solution

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\missing2\ToBeDeleted.txt") do (
    del "C:\Users\gggggg\Desktop\missing2\%%a"
)
```

Comment: "Thanks" @MC ND this is just what i needed. Get-Content "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\missing2\ToBeDeleted.txt" | Remove-Item           Thanks for your help to all

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b /a-d "FolderA*"|findstr /g:"FolderA\list.txt"
```

should do what you appear to want.

What has "FolderB" go to do with the problem?

--- er, you want to delete files that are not in the list `list.txt` ?

Well, the above should give you a list of files-to-be-deleted, so

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "FolderA*"^|findstr /g:"FolderA\list.txt"') do ECHO(del "FolderA\%%a"
```

should `echo` the same list. If it is correct, change the `echo(del`to `del` **after verification** to actually delete the files.